# Applying CSS3 Pie.htc to html body

Tags: css, css3pie

I'm trying to use PIE.htc (with IE8) to get elements displaying with border radius etc.

Is there a way to apply `behavior: url(/path/to/PIE.htc);` to all the elements in body tag in one rule or do I have to write the rule for every single element I want to use PIE.htc on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have to specify the PIE behavior for each CSS element that needs the PIE help, but you can use one rule to do it.  For example, if you have 3 classed divs and every image in the main wrapper that need PIE's assistance to render CSS3 elements in IE8:

```
div.callout, div.special, div.best, #wrapper img { behavior: url(/path/to/PIE.htc); }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I started specifying elements to add PIE behavior to them. I wish there was an easy way (just specifying this rule for whole body element or something like that), but I have to settle for that solution - after all border radius is finally working in IE8 and my nerves are saved :)